# Water on basement floor and attempting to fix with mortar?

Tags: water, basement, waterproofing, water-pressure, mortar

I have waterproofed my basement completely for three sides (digging and using membrane and installing weeping tile), but for the remaining side which is a sidewalk, it would be too expensive to bust all the concrete. For the sidewalk, I have sealed the edge between the sidewalk and where it touches my house from the outside.

But for a section of the side walk side inside the house, I have seen water still accumulates after raining. I have ripped out the wall, and found no cracks on that wall (just some honey comb), and it looks as though the water came from the bottom of the wall (but I see no obvious cracks).

I have asked a contractor (foundation/concrete guy) and he said he can put special mix of mortar at the corner at the end of that wall.

My question is, what do you think causes the water in that section to accumulates? And do you think the contractor's mortar advise is the way to go?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Basement water problems can never be solved on the inside with a sealer or mortar.  Surface water must drain away from the house at grade level.  The crack letting water in is where floor and wall meet and may not be visible to the eye.  If surface water drains toward the foundation it will run down the outside of the wall.  Once enough of this has happened hydrostatic pressure will push the water thru the wall/floor joint.

Comment: If I don't do anything (due to the cost), and if I can live with occasional water accumulation in that part of the basement, and just leave it be. Will it be worsening over the long run? Or it will be ok?

Comment: It gets worse, not to mention mold and mildew that it will create is a health risk.

Comment: Is there anything I can do other than busting the concrete from the outside? Also, there is a window well directly above, do you think it may be the source? Another thing is this room is about the length of one third of the side of the sidewalk basement, the other two-third of the basement has no water issues after I sealed where the sidewalk and my house meet from the outside.

Comment: Does water run down the wall on the inside from the window? Can you post a picture of the problem area outside?

Comment: There used to have water running down the basement inside wall, and there used to have a large gap between the sidewalk and along where it meets the house on the outside. I sealed the entire length with caulking (though there are still window wells - the contractor suggested pouring concrete to seal the window wells since there is no weeping tile underneath). Since then I don't see water dripping down the wall anymore, but still see water on the floor (sorry, don't have more pictures at the moment).

Comment: Your contractor may be thinking about hydraulic cement. This may slow it but won't stop it. I would dig a pit at the leak point and install a sump pump. This would be less expensive than removing the sidewalk and contain the water to be pumped out. But the only sure fire way is to seal and drain from the outside like you have done on the other walls.